# Pass Type to Expression Func Out

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, func

I need to be able to get the type from the `currentStep` variable and use that type for the `newExpression` assignment. What this code is doing is changing the `Expression` out type. Is there a way where I can dynamically set the `newExpression` func out type based on the currentStep type?

```
PropertyInfo currentStep = wizardTransaction.GetCurrentStepPropertyInfo();

string currentStepName = wizardTransaction.GetCurrentStepPropertyInfo().PropertyType.Name;

var body = Expression.Property(expression.Body, currentStepName);

var newExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, **currentStep.GetType()**>>(body, expression.Parameters[0]);

var model = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(newExpression, helper.ViewData).Model;
```

The method which the above code is in is a `static` class so the answer thats the solution that this is marked as a duplicate for does not apply as the `this` keyword used in the accepted answer cant not be used in a `static` class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use reflection to call a generic method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method)

Comment: I can't use that solution as it states to use generic.Invoke(this, null); But my class is static so the this keyword can not be used.

Comment: Pass null for the object-instance parameter if you want to call a static method.

Comment: So how do I incorporate their answer with mine? I need to use the type against my newExpression Expression.

Comment: @BadDub You do not need to use `this` to call `Invoke`. Also, there are `Expression.Lambda` that accept delegate type as normal parameter, but not as generic argument.

Comment: Checking out the Expression.Lambda now. Will let you know how I get on.

Comment: @PetSerAl when I use the Expression.Lamda you were talking about the next line 'ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(newExpression, helper.ViewData).Model;' fails as I now have to provide that with the types.

Comment: Then provide these types?

Comment: But its the same problem as the original question. I'm just moving the problem down one line.

Comment: Thats what you have to life with when using reflection. reflection trades type-safetyness for flexibility.